# Наиболее подходящий язык для парсинга страниц vk.com

Tags: вконтакте, синтаксический-анализ

Появилась острая необходимость поработать со страничкой vk.com. В частности пробежаться по всем подписчикам сообщества, узнать кто он-лайн кто нет. Вывести всю информацию в файл.
Какой язык программирования больше подходит для данной задачи? Или же есть библиотеки подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Парсить vk не надо, надо работать с [Vkontakte API](http://vk.com/dev/methods). Например:

- [Получить список участников группы](http://vk.com/dev/groups.getMembers)
- [Получить информацию о пользователях](http://vk.com/dev/users.get)
- и т.д.

Данные возвращаются в формате JSON, а уж на каком языке их разбирать и какими инструментами делать запросы - уже вкусовщина.